# Multiple similar forms in same page

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

In Spring Boot with Thymeleaf, I have a page that should handle two forms corresponding to a same model `Person`. Each form can be submitted separately, so I use two methods in the controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value="/", params={"submitFather"})
    public String submitFather(
            @ModelAttribute("fatherForm") Person fatherForm,
            @ModelAttribute("motherForm") Person motherForm,
            Model model) {

        // ... Process fatherForm

        // Return the updated page
        model.addAttribute("fatherForm", fatherForm);
        model.addAttribute("motherForm", motherForm);
        return "index.html";
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/", params={"submitMother"})
    public String submitMother(
            @ModelAttribute("fatherForm") Person fatherForm,
            @ModelAttribute("motherForm") Person motherForm,
            Model model) {

        // ... Process motherForm

        // Return the updated page
        model.addAttribute("fatherForm", fatherForm);
        model.addAttribute("motherForm", motherForm);
        return "index.html";
    }
```

In my template:

```
<form id="fatherForm" th:object="${fatherForm}" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"><br>

    <!-- ... other Person fields -->

    <input type="submit" name="submitFather" value="Order">
</form>

<form id="motherForm" th:object="${motherForm}" method="post">
    <label for="firstName">First name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}"><br>

    <!-- ... other Person fields -->

    <input type="submit" name="submitMother" value="Order">
</form>
```

The issue I have is that this leads to HTML IDs clashes. There will be for example two `<input>` with id `firstName`. This causes invalid HTML and interference between the fields from the two forms when submitted.

One solution would be to have two models, `Father` and `Mother` with fields named such as `fatherFirstName` to ensure no duplicate HTML IDs. But this leads to substantial code duplication, and long and different field names (while only the HTML IDs need to be different).

How can this be solved? Is there a way to tell Spring to prefix ids with some string while ensuring I can still use the same `Person` model for the two forms?